# prove $f^{-1}(z)=\{(x_1,x_2)|f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1}{x_2}=z\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $S^3$ is a $3-$dimensional sphere and $S^2$ is a $2-$dimensional sphere. We define $f:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ which satisfies $$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$$when $x_2=0,\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\infty$.

> How to prove that $f^{-1}(z)=\{(x_1,x_2)|f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1}{x_2}=z\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Answer (score 1):

$$|x_2|^2=\frac1{(1+|z|^2)}$$
describes the set with one parameter. Notice this is an equation for a circle.

You can make use of this parameterization to define a homeomorphism with $S^1$, namely
$$x\mapsto \left(\frac{xz}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}},\frac x{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}\right)$$